# PostgreSQL connection using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am new to databases and have been trying to connect to PostgreSQL database for a while now using python, i have even tried changing to pgSQL, but I still get errors. I have tried SEARCHING for solutions  but no success. I am using windows 10 + pgSQL 9.5 & python 3.6.4.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='wildlife', user='postgres', password='P@$$w0rd', host='localhost', port='5432')
print("opened the database successfully")

cur = conn.cursor()

while true:
    with cur.execute('SELECT * FROM CAGE;') as j:
       rows = cur.fetchall()
       for row in rows:
           if item == j:            
               print ("ID = "), row[0]
               print ("NAME = "), row[1]
               print ("LIVES = "), row[2]
               print ("WEIGHT = "), row[3]
               print ("LEGS = "), row[4]
               print ("CLASS = "), row[5]
               print ("NUMBER = "), row[6]
               print ("CATEGORY = "), row[7]

conn.close()
```

I do not what I am missing or what I have done that is wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ignat\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 85, in <module>
    import ptvsd
  File "c:\Users\ignat\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._vendored import force_pydevd
  File "c:\Users\ignat\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\force_pydevd.py", line 20, in <module>
    pydevd_constants = import_module('_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants')
  File "E:\LOTUS\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\Users\ignat\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_constants.py", line 164, in <module>
    from _pydev_imps._pydev_saved_modules import thread
  File "c:\Users\ignat\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_saved_modules.py", line 21, in <module>
    import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpclib
  File "E:\LOTUS\python\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 135, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "E:\LOTUS\python\lib\decimal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _decimal import *
  File "d:\LOTUS\Documents\my projects\DataCode\numbers.py", line 12
    continue
           ^
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
```

but now am getting the same error over and over again. no matter what I add or what I change. help me out.

Comment: Please post the complete traceback. Also, the code in your question is not valid in Python 3.6

Comment: what is item?? and what you want to achieve with `item==j`

Comment: don't use `*`, use explicit column names. The return value of `execute` is None and cannot be used with `with`.

Comment: well i have tried also the proper "valid" python code, and i was getting back the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with your current code.
In your current directory there is a file `numbers.py` with errors.
You must not name your files like python standard modules. Rename `numbers.py` to another name and remove any `numbers.pyc` file.

Comment: i checked it out and you were right, i did remove the file and the error stopped. Though now, the script wont RUN, or i cannot debug. i am going to figure that out. Thanks